# How to load tiles onto a SCNSphere?

Tags: ios, scenekit, watchos-3

I want to dynamically load tiles and display them on a `SCNSphere`. Of course I can assign a `UIImage` to the `SCNMaterial`:

```
sphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = image
```

However that means that I've to merge all tiles together in a huge `UIImage` first. And I have to do that each time a new tile is fetched. A `CATiledLayer` based `SCNMaterial` would be another option but sadly it's not available on Apple Watch.

Is there a way to keep the tiles separate in SceneKit? I tried using multiple materials for the sphere but that didn't work.

Comment: How big are these tiles? Can you make them really small, with coarse resolution? Putting huge images onto Apple Watch seems like overkill.

Comment: The tiles are 512x512. Of course on Apple Watch there will be much fewer (4-8) as on iOS (up to 64).

Comment: If the tiles are seamless then you can probably use `SCNWrapModeRepeat`...

Comment: They are not seamless. Each tile is different.